# How to achieve smooth window scroll in angular2

Tags: angular, scroll

For window scrolling, Currently I am using window.scrollTo() in angular2. Is any other way to achieve smooth scrolling in angular2.

Comment: Angular doesn't provide anything by itself. How would you do it in plain JS or AngularJS?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll

Comment: ng2-page-scroll easing functions (it's linear on default) turn out to behave weird.

Answer (score 1):

1. Works only for Chrome, Firefox, Opera:

   ```
   html{
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
   }
   ```
2. Works on all browsers: npm install scroll-behaviour

   component.ts

   ```
   smoothScroll(element) {
     (document.querySelector(element)).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
   }
   ```

   component.html

   ```
   <a (click)="smoothScroll('#about-sector')"> About</a>
   ```